# pymeshlab not installing in macbook air m2

Tags: macos, pymeshlab

I'm having trouble installing pymeshlab on my macbook air M2 2022. Do the newer macbook models support meshlab?

```
pip3 install pymeshlab

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymeshlab (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymeshlab
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this reply, PyMeshLab will not be supporting ARM architecture any time soon. [Reply](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/PyMeshLab/issues/71)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can install it like this?

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/PyMeshLab
```

Found it in PyMeshLab [docs](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/0.1.6/installation.html).